# Divisors of sequence $1!+2!+\ldots+n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is the set of prime numbers which divide at least one number in the sequence $a_n=1!+2!+\ldots+n!$ finite or infinite?

I try to show that it's infinite. Suppose the set is finite and consists of $p_1<p_2<\ldots<p_k$. Consider $n>p_k$. We have $a_n=1!+2!+\ldots+p_k!+(p_k+1)!\ldots+n!$. The terms from $(p_k+1)!$ onward are divisible by $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$. The problem is that we do not have control over the power of $p_i$ that divides $1!+2!+\ldots+p_k!$ and $(p_k+1)!\ldots+n!$.

Comment: For any single prime $p$, what must happen for $p$ to divide $1! + \cdots + (p-1)!$?

Comment: @Arthur $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod p$, so $(p-2)!\equiv (p-1)^{-1}\pmod p$, etc., but it's not clear when your division condition happens

Comment: Your question is equivalent to asking whether my division condition holds for an infinite number of primes. I do not know the answer. By the way, how does $n!$ behave mod prime $p$ for $1<n<p$? Perhaps we can get somewhere from there.

Comment: It might be useful to note that
$$
(p-k)! = -(p-1)^{-1} \cdots (p-k)^{-1} = -(-1)^{-1} \cdots (-k)^{-1} = (-1)^{k+1} (k!)^{-1} \pmod p
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sequence gets a mention in Guy's [Unsolved Problems in Number Theory](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=1AP2CEGxTkgC&lpg=PA153&ots=TkiBf1ALuA&dq=Unsolved%20Problems%20in%20Number%20Theory%20Kurepa&pg=PA153#v=onepage&q&f=false) (3-rd edition, 2004); denoted $K_n$ below:

[image: Unsolved Problems in Number Theory snippet]

So I suspect you might not get a conclusive answer.  I would guess it's infinite.

Here's a table for small values:

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|}
\hline
n & \text{prime factorization of } a_n \\
\hline
1 &  1  \\
2 &  3  \\
3 &  3 \cdot 3  \\
4 &  3 \cdot 11  \\
5 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 17  \\
6 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 97  \\
7 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 73  \\
8 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 467  \\
9 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 131 \cdot 347  \\
10 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 40787  \\
11 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 443987  \\
12 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 11 \cdot 23 \cdot 20879  \\
13 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 821 \cdot 83047  \\
14 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 2789 \cdot 340183  \\
15 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 107 \cdot 509 \cdot 259949  \\
16 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 225498914387  \\
17 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 163 \cdot 20143 \cdot 1162943  \\
18 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 19727 \cdot 3471827581  \\
19 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 29 \cdot 43 \cdot 1621 \cdot 641751001  \\
20 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 11 \cdot 53 \cdot 67 \cdot 662348503367  \\
21 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 877 \cdot 3203 \cdot 41051 \cdot 4699727  \\
22 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 11895484822660898387  \\
23 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 139 \cdot 2129333 \cdot 922459185301  \\
24 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 37 \cdot 37 \cdot 29131483 \cdot 163992440081  \\
25 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 454823 \cdot 519472957 \cdot 690821017  \\
26 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 107 \cdot 173 \cdot 7823 \cdot 12227 \cdot 1281439 \cdot 1867343  \\
27 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 431363 \cdot 2882477797 \cdot 91865833117  \\
28 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 191 \cdot 47793258077 \cdot 349882390108241  \\
29 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 37 \cdot 283 \cdot 5087 \cdot 1736655143086866180331  \\
30 &  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 2771826449193354891007108898387  \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

One might even suspect that $a_n$ is $99$ times a prime infinitely often (see Sloane's http://oeis.org/A122990).

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to note that the sequence in Guy's book is $1$ off from  my sequence, because it has the term $0!$. I'm not sure what that implies about the set of prime divisors with respect to the two sequences.